# Meteor Environment - Blank and Everything Broken

Tags: meteor

I got to a point where Meteor seemed to just stop working, no HTML would load but the port was open, throwing basic console errors indicating that the most basic parts of the program weren't getting read.

After a lot of troubleshooting (clearing the database, restarting, logging out, using different ports), I just created a new Meteor project and copied and pasted my .html and .js files and the new project worked where the old project didn't.

So, question - how can I troubleshoot this in the future? Something was going on in the Meteor folder because the old and new files were exactly the same.

After a day, the error is happening all the time now and I can't create a single project. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Meteor with no luck.

Also, the problem seems to be isolated to one port. I can open projects in other ports, but not in 3000.

Why is one port "breaking"? What can I do to fix this?

[image: Console Logs and Structure of Fresh Meteor Project called 'coolapp']

--Edit--
The HTML and CSS are loading, but in the default port 3000, the console reads

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined`

It shows this code as the first error point:

`/* Imports */
var Meteor = Package.meteor.Meteor;`

Below is the Terminal:

[image: Terminal for creating new 'coolapp' meteor project]

--Edit--

So this is embarrassing, it seemed to be a cache problem. I cleared the cache, and I'm assuming it refreshed the .js files and now it works.

**If anyone can answer *why* the errors were being thrown in the first place and how to fix besides creating an entirely new project, that would be hugely helpful!**

Answer (score 1):

please post your terminal so we have more clues to help you.
You definitely can run other ports, perhaps your port 3000 is used by another program.
Also, never run a meteor app as root.

Run meteor on a high port number. The default is 3000 when you don't give a --port argument. Connect to it via the URL printed in the console - e.g.

```
meteor --port 3001
```

http://localhost:3000/.

If you have settings.json then run meteor --settings settings.json

Comment: nevermind - I should have taken a screenshot of server terminal. If this happens again, I'll post another Q, but I think I'll take this question down.